How can I integrate AWS SDK for C++ in my Android C++ project
I have a Juce Framework C++ Android App and want to integrate AWS SDK for C++ so that I can upload files to the my s3 bucket.
I have already built the SDK from GitHub successfully.
Problem is I can't find any documentation or videos on how to do it except for https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/welcome.html which is not related to my current problem.
I have tried adding the build headers to my CMakeList.txt file but Android Studio can't find AWS headers.
